# getimagesize cpanel with php 5.5.8

Tags: php, gd, cpanel, getimagesize

My VPS use PHP 5.5.8
when i test

```
<?php
$size = getimagesize('http://donikids.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tu-dung-do-choi-tre-em-gk137.jpg');
var_dump($size);
?>
```

This error

> Warning: getimagesize(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /home/donikids/public_html/test.php on line 2
>   Warning: getimagesize(http://donikids.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tu-dung-do-choi-tre-em-gk137.jpg): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /home/donikids/public_html/test.php on line 2
>   bool(false)

You can check here
http://donikids.com/test.php

Please help me

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
<?php
$size = getimagesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tu-dung-do-choi-tre-em-gk137.jpg');
var_dump($size);
?>
```

Comment: I try it, success, but i want to this url

Comment: it is the same url where your image is exists in the directory. it gives the root path of your directory.

Comment: `http://donikids.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tu-dung-do-choi-tre-em-gk137.jpg` is your browser path of url. you need physical path of your image on the server to use `getimagesize` see http://in1.php.net/getimagesize

Comment: Thank all, i used path of image